# Do something at background, ONCE finished, do something else at foreground?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, default

We face with similar situation. Say we want to get data from the web. So, we grab data from background. After that we're back and update some view based on the new data.

Should I do this:

```
__block NSDictionary * dic = nil;
__block NSObject* lock = [[NSObject alloc]init];

[Tools doBackground:^{
    @synchronized (lock) {
        dic=(NSDictionary *)[GrabClass JsonParser:alamat];
    }
}];
@synchronized (lock)
{
}

NSString *countView= [[dic objectForKey:[BNUtilitiesQuick currentBusiness].ID] objectForKey:@"CountViews"];
```

... bla bla bla

or should I do

```
[Tools doBackground:^{
        dic=(NSDictionary *)[GrabClass JsonParser:alamat];
    //}
    [Tools doForeGround:^{
        NSString *countView= [[dic objectForKey:businessReviewed.ID] objectForKey:@"CountViews"];

        CLog(@"countView:%@", countView);
        NSString *countReview=[[dic objectForKey:businessReviewed.ID] objectForKey:@"Review"];
```

Of course:

`NSString *countReview=[[dic objectForKey:businessReviewed.ID] objectForKey:@"Review"];` 
must be called after `dic=(NSDictionary *)[GrabClass JsonParser:alamat];` is finished, needless to say.

Also this is the definition of doForeGround and doBackGround

```
+(void)doForeGround:(void (^)())block
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        block();
    });
}

+(void)doBackground:(void (^)())block
{
    //DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(-2,0), ^{
        block();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example how to use GCD

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);

    //Do stuff async in the backbround
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
            //Fetch data sync. When its done... update.
        });

        //Update on the main thread
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Do some updates
        });
    });
```

Comment: I know how to use dispatch_sync. I am asking what's the best, the second or first method?

Comment: This code has a high chance of deadlock. You should not call `dispatch_sync()` on a queue to put a task on that same queue. (For a serial queue, deadlock would be guaranteed.)

Comment: The example is taken from downloading images from the book "Concurrent programming in Mac and iOS". http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020332.do but just because its a book its not fail safe. Could you elaborate a little bit more. Should you use a different queue for the sync call (background thread)?

Comment: Actually what I do now is having a bunch of different threads.

Comment: Jim wouldn't it be much better to use GCD instead of creating your own threads!?

Comment: Yes, you need a different queue. The situation you're creating is: `dispatch_sync()` does not return until the block it enqueues is done executing, but that new block is on the queue _after_ the block in which the `dispatch_sync()` call is made; it can't begin executing on a serial queue until that block finishes. This is deadlock: the enclosing block is waiting on the `dispatch_sync()`, which is waiting on the new block, which is waiting on the enclosing block. If the concurrent queue doesn't have enough resources to run the new block simultaneously to the enclosing one, the same will happen.